# Chromecast sender APIs for WebView based app on Android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, chromecast, android-4.4-kitkat

I read that WebView component in Android 4.4 is based on Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview#does_the_webview_support_the_chrome_apps_apis

However, support for Chrome Apps API is still not there. Does this mean that my WebView based app cannot use Chromecast Sender APIs ?

Answer (score 4):

That is correct, you do not have the needed extension and APIs to use the (pure) chrome WebView to communicate with a chromecast device. As a side note, you cannot do that in the full Chrome on Android either.

Answer (score 1):

I think Chromecast is one of those things that doesn't come with Chromium (the opensource project where Chrome is based upon) and Android uses Chromium for the webview, not Chrome :)