# Chromecast-ing a WebView?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

My current application uses a WebView to display HTML5 & CSS3 content (some animations).

Is it possible to "cast" this WebView to a Chromecast, in effect, mirroring what is displayed on the main device?

Comment: I'm afraid not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797403/chromecast-sender-apis-for-webview-based-app-on-android-4-4

Comment: That is not currently supported.

Comment: So, is there simply no Webview on the ChromeCast? Or is it a case of you can only instruct the ChromeCast to visit a URL?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as WebView does not implement the Chromecast API.

I had raised an issue on the Android Tracker [WebView does not implement the Chromecast API](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/193047894)

It's closed as Won't Fix.

The solution here would be to use the exoplayer-cast-extension.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this possible actually.
I made something identical for the company i work for.(so i cant share code)
You nead to write a custom receiver for the chromecast running trough a HTTPS connection

Comment: can you give some more instructions how to implement/realize it please?

Comment: This is definitely not an answer, but a teaser.

Comment: i know but i cant share the code. here is a link :https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver

Comment: You could post more details without source codes. First of all, it's not clear why do we need a custom receiver? The question implies sending data to the standard chromecast receiver already running on every dongle. The process of registration, debugging, and publishing of your own receiver is rather tedious and looks like overkill in most "client side" use cases, imho.

Comment: No, actually its even better for the cliënt. Chromecast can pull the html  of a server so the cliënt can just send a url. The custom receiver is needed because google deceided that chromecast by default only accepts media.

Comment: Yes, I know about the server hosting a receiver app (which still requires a lot of overheads imho, but never mind). So, if the dongle accepts media by default, is it possible to send url with a media to the default receiver?